# Can not install xzdec by tlmgr

Tags: texlive, tlmgr

I installed texlive by script so I can have the latest version.

When using xetex it gives the following error message:

> I can't find the format file `xetex.fmt'!
>
> sudo fmtutil-sys --all

did not helped.

another solution is:

> sudo tlmgr install latex latex-bin

I gives the error message:

> /usr/bin/tlmgr: could not find a usable xzdec.

using tlmgr to install xzdec gives the same error message.

Installing xzdec from ubuntu repository gives the following error message:

> Unknown directive ...containerchecksum 06c8c1fff8b025f6f55f8629af6e41a6dd695e13bbdfe8b78b678e9cb0cfa509826355f4ece20d8a99b49bcee3c5931b8d766f0fc3dae0d6a645303d487600b0... , please fix it! at /usr/share/texlive/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPOBJ.pm line 210,  line 5761.

Which is logical because there not the same version.

How can I install xzdec?

Thanks

Comment: the unknown directive I think means that you are running an old pre-2017 tlmgr but trying to update from the current 2017 repository which includes a checksum check on file transfers,.

Comment: is the texlive you installed in /usr/bin or is that a pre-existing system installation? If you have installed a texlive from tug it's usually in /usr/local/texlive/2017

Comment: texlive is installed in /usr/local/texlive/2017.

Comment: in that case you need to fix your path or explicitly use the tlmgr from there and not the one you are using from /usr/bin/tlmgr